# how to get a complete command of X apps via 'wmctl' and 'ps'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ps, wmctrl

I'm working on [a program](https://github.com/nlpsuge/save-restore-opened-apps) that can query running X apps, save all the commands of running apps and them reopen them latter.

I encounter an issue. wmctctl can query the pid of [Onlyoffice](https://www.onlyoffice.com/download-desktop.aspx), for example the pid is 123. Then run `ps -ef -q 123`, I see that the CMD is `./DesktopEditors` which should be a invalid command, because `./one_command` only can work in special folder include file one_command.

I can get a complete command by running `ps -ef -q $(pgrep -P 123)`.

Is there a straight way to get the complete command of Onlyoffice just via `wmctl` and `ps`?

If there is a better way to get all commands of X apps, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `ps -h -e -o pid,args` command piped with a `grep`

This should provide full command path with it arguments and options.

For example find all running java programs with their arguments (might be extensive):

```
ps -eo pid,args | grep java
```

In your case I suggest a small awk script, that looks for the pid given as 3rd input field in current line:

```
wmctrl -l -p|awk '{system("ps -h --pid "$3" -o args")}'
```

#### Sample output

```
nautilus-desktop --force
/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
```

#### update

Transforming current directory `./` to  to full path.
Assuming `./` represent the current working directory. 
Add the following pipe.

```
wmctrl -l -p|awk '{system("ps -h --pid "$3" -o args")}'|sed "s|^\./|$PWD/|"
```

Find the script or program `DesktopEditors` in your computer, using `find / -name "DesktopEditors"`.

But I believe this is useless if you are trying to reverse engineer a web based application that requires some kind of a browser emulator.

Comment: Your code maybe will simplify my code. Thanks. But if I run Onlyoffice. I only get `./DesktopEditors` if execute the command `wmctrl -l -p|awk '{system("ps -h --pid "$3" -o args")}'|grep Desktop`.

Comment: I want to get the complete command of Onlyoffice, not just `./DesktopEditors`.

Comment: than you replace ./ with $PWD. I added update to the answer.